# Animation with Timer in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, animation, timer, basic

I'm trying to create an animation when clicking a button by using a timer. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Animate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Animate.Click
        Timer.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    Dim m As Integer = 0
    m = m + 1

    Select Case m
        Case 1
            Me.Arrow4.Visible = True
            Me.Arrow5.Visible = True
            Me.Arrow6.Visible = True
        Case 2
            Me.Arrow1.Visible = True
            Me.Label1.Visible = True
            Me.Arrow4.Visible = False
            Me.Arrow5.Visible = False
            Me.Arrow6.Visible = False
        Case 3
            Me.Arrow2.Visible = True
            Me.Label2.Visible = True
            Me.Arrow1.Visible = False
            Me.Label1.Visible = False
        Case 4
            Me.Arrow3.Visible = True
            Me.Label3.Visible = True
            Me.Arrow2.Visible = False
            Me.Label2.Visible = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

The first case shows, but not the rest of it. I set the interval for the timer at 1.

Thanks!

Comment: On every timer tick you are setting `m` to 0 and then adding 1. It will always be 1 when you execute the `Select Case`. Instead, declare `m` **outside** the Timer_Tick Sub. `Private m As Integer`, and set it to 0 in the Animate_Click Sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rest of the cases will never show because you are always instantiating `m` to 0 within the scope of the timer's method.  `m` will always be 1 when the case statement is hit.  You'll need to move `m` outside the scope of the timer at a class level if you want to persist the value.  Just don't forget to set `m` back to 0 when you hit your last case. e.g.

```
...

Case 4
   Me.Arrow3.Visible = True
   Me.Label3.Visible = True
   Me.Arrow2.Visible = False
   Me.Label2.Visible = False
   m = 0     

...
```